# Firebase Cloud Function config to access other project db

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I need to create a Cloud Function that will access the Firebase DB that is running in another project. If it was accessing the db in the current project, I could use code such as

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

however, what I want is for `functions.config().firebase` to return the information (and, most importantly, credentials) for the other project. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`functions.config().firebase` is a reserved namespace and you won't be able to override it. However, you *can* do cross-project initialization yourself. Here's how I would do it:

First, [download a service account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app) for your other project into your `functions` directory. Name it `<project_id>-sa.json`. Next, set up some environment config (`app.other_project_id` is just an example name, not a requirement):

```
firebase functions:config:set app.other_project_id="<the_project_id>"
```

Now in your code, you can initialize the Admin SDK like so:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

if (!functions.config().app || !functions.config().app.other_project_id) {
  throw new Error('Cannot start app without app.other_project_id config.');
}

const FB_PROJECT_ID = functions.config().app.other_project_id;
const SERVICE_ACCOUNT = require(`./${FB_PROJECT_ID}-sa.json`);

admin.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: `https://${FB_PROJECT_ID}.firebaseio.com`,
  credential: admin.credential.cert(SERVICE_ACCOUNT)
});
```

This will have initialized the Admin SDK for the other project.

Comment: Thanks. This was along the lines of what I feared I would have to do. I was avoiding it because (1) All my other configuration is in... Firebase DB. So putting just one thing in functions.config() was annoying. (2) I prefer to avoid using (and deploying) files that shouldn't be in revision control. But I suspect this will be roughly be the solution I'll go with.

Comment: This approach works really well if you want to implement a REST API hosted in another Firebase project, and need to consume information of another Firebase project.

Comment: It is probably a terrible idea to push those json credentials into a repo.

Comment: Yup. `.gitignore` is your friend here

Comment: Could you specify what would happen if I have admin.intializeApp() on my global scope and then initialize another app? Would my other firebase-admin imports break?

Comment: @MichaelBleigh, isn't it feasible to grant [Firebase Realtime Database roles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-product#realtime-database) in the project B to the [service account `project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/service-accounts) of the project A that is [used for running cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56618369/3082178) to avoid explicitly specifying credential?

Comment: @AKd yes, you should be able to grant cross-project roles for this purpose. That would be an alternative way to do the above.

Answer (score 1):

**2023 ANSWER:**

You can [initialize multiple Admin apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-multiple-apps) in a Cloud function as shown below:

```js
// Initialize the default app
initializeApp(defaultAppConfig);
const otherApp = initializeApp(otherAppConfig, 'other');

const defaultFirestore = getFirestore();
const otherFirestore = getFirestore(otherApp);
```

Here you can use `defaultFirestore` to read from first Firestore project and then `otherFirestore` to write in another.

Answer (score -1):

instead of

```
if (!functions.config().app || !functions.config().app.project_id) {
```

You should use

```
if (!functions.config().app || !functions.config().app.fb_project_id) {
```

NOTE: the typo in project_id

Comment: It is supposed to be an edit to the accepted answer, not a separate answer.